# How to use System.Drawing on Mac OS?

Tags: .net, macos, system.drawing

1. Run NuGet Package manager
2. Add "System.Drawing.Common"
3. Add `using System.Drawing`
   I still cannot use Point or Image in my code.

.csproj file does have

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.7.0"/>
```

Comment: [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netcore-3.1) is in [`System.Drawing.Primitives`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Primitives/).

Comment: What kind of project? Please share the whole project file.

Comment: @LexLi - <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.7.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Comment: @LexLi how do I know upfront what info is necessary? Did this info lead you to the answer?

Comment: @BACON Didn't address the issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the part of "I still cannot use Point or Image in my code". You probably need to share the complete project somewhere for others to review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) working in OSX by also adding the [runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing) NuGet package.

Note that my OSX test platform is Azure Pipelines. You can look over [my csproj file](https://github.com/swharden/ScottPlot/blob/master/src/ScottPlot/ScottPlot.csproj) if you find it helpful. It contains:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing" Version="5.8.64" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.7.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Don't forget to add a using statement to the top of your CS files:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Install nuget [runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing) to allows you to use System.Drawing.Common on macOS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).